# How to update a related table when a new connection item is created?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I have 3 tables in an SQL server

*LaptopTable*: LaptopID(int), LaptopName(nvarchar), LaptopAvailable(bit)

*PersonTable*: PersonID(int), PersonName(nvarchar)

*ConnectionTable*: ConnectionID(int),  LaptopLaptopID(int), PersonPersonID(int)

In ASP.NET EF Core (web) I made a CRUD for all three tables. How can I set the LaptopAvailable bit to false in the LaptopTable when a new connection item is created?

Here’s my “Create” part from my ConnectionsController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ConnectionID,LaptopLaptopID,PersonPersonID")] Connection connection)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
_context.Add(connection);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
ViewData["LaptopLaptopID"] = new SelectList(_context.Laptops, "LaptopID", "LaptopName", connection.LaptopLaptopID);
ViewData["PersonPersonID"] = new SelectList(_context.Persons, "PersonID", "PersonName", connection.PersonPersonID);
return View(connection);
}
```

Comment: Since you have the laptop id, you can find the laptop record, update the flag and then SaveChanges

Comment: I agree, but how do I translate that to code. I fail to perform an update to my LaptopTable while creating a connection record in my ConnectionTable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain the existing Laptop record from the LaptopId of connection and update that.

```cs
// Add connection
_context.Add(connection);

// Find & update flag for that laptop
var existingLaptop = _context.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LaptopId == connection.LaptopLaptopID)
if(existingLaptop)
    existingLaptop.LaptopAvailable = false;

// Save both changes
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It should be something like that. The .FirstOrDefault gives a red squiggly line though.

Comment: You have to add using statement for that!